# Dataframe name R

Tags: r, excel, date, dataframe

I import a .csv file (from Excel 2010) in R through the `read.cv2()` function.

I get a `dataframe`. My column's names should be dates, but I get something like `X08.03.2013`.

I have several questions :

1. How can I set those names as a Date format (idem for the line's names) ?
2. For columns, once I got the date format, how can I use condition (if) on these Dates ?

I hope I have been clear enough.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: try `check.names=FALSE` as argument to `read.csv()`

Comment: second part of your question is unclear. Do you want to select columns whose names satisfy certain condition?

Comment: Thank you. I don't get the X anymore.

Comment: @geektrader  How can I convert those columns' names in Date format now ?

Comment: @Henri Column Names are `characters` they can't be `Dates`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little example for you to try:

#### Make up some data and try to read it in

```
# This just creates a CSV in your current working directory to play with
cat("08-03-2013;08-04-2013;08-05-2013\n0,5;0,5;0,5\n0,6;0,6;0,6\n", 
    file = "FunkyNames.csv")
read.csv2("FunkyNames.csv")
#   X08.03.2013 X08.04.2013 X08.05.2013
# 1         0.5         0.5         0.5
# 2         0.6         0.6         0.6
read.csv2("FunkyNames.csv", check.names = FALSE)
#   08-03-2013 08-04-2013 08-05-2013
# 1        0.5        0.5        0.5
# 2        0.6        0.6        0.6
```

As you can see, using `read.csv2()` along with `check.names = FALSE` works to get the names as they are in your input file. Now, let's use that and try to extract some data.

```
temp <- read.csv2("FunkyNames.csv", check.names = FALSE)
## Our first attempt doesn't work
temp$08-03-2013
# Error: unexpected numeric constant in "temp$08"

## Using quotes works
temp$"08-03-2013"
# [1] 0.5 0.6

## The following would work too
## temp$`08-03-2013`
## temp$'08-03-2013'
```

#### A more efficient way to extract certain columns

A more efficient way to extract certain columns would be to create a separate vector of the `names` of the `data.frame`, convert those to dates using `as.Date`, and then using that vector to subset from your original `data.frame`. Some examples:

```
tempCols <- as.Date(names(temp), format = "%m-%d-%Y")
tempCols
temp[tempCols > "2013-08-04"]
#   08-05-2013
# 1        0.5
# 2        0.6
temp[tempCols >= "2013-08-04"]
#   08-04-2013 08-05-2013
# 1        0.5        0.5
# 2        0.6        0.6
```

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks a lot to both of you ! It really helps. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your two question.

1. You load your csv using `check.names=FALSE` argument
2. Column names can't be `dates`. They need to be `characters`.

You can however do character based search on the column names and select only those columns which satisfy certain requirement

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample(10), sample(10)))
names(df) <- c("08.03.2013", "09.03.2013")
df
##    08.03.2013 09.03.2013
## 1           8         10
## 2           3          8
## 3           4          3
## 4           1          9
## 5           5          5
## 6           6          4
## 7          10          6
## 8           9          7
## 9           2          1
## 10          7          2


# Either do character based search using regex
df[, grep("08.03.2013", names(df)), drop = FALSE]
##    08.03.2013
## 1           8
## 2           3
## 3           4
## 4           1
## 5           5
## 6           6
## 7          10
## 8           9
## 9           2
## 10          7

df[, grep("09.03.2013", names(df)), drop = FALSE]
##    09.03.2013
## 1          10
## 2           8
## 3           3
## 4           9
## 5           5
## 6           4
## 7           6
## 8           7
## 9           1
## 10          2


# Or even convert names to Dates and then compare.
df[, as.Date(names(df), format = "%d.%m.%Y") == as.Date("2013-03-08"), drop = FALSE]
##    08.03.2013
## 1           8
## 2           3
## 3           4
## 4           1
## 5           5
## 6           6
## 7          10
## 8           9
## 9           2
## 10          7

df[, as.Date(names(df), format = "%d.%m.%Y") > as.Date("2013-03-08"), drop = FALSE]
##    09.03.2013
## 1          10
## 2           8
## 3           3
## 4           9
## 5           5
## 6           4
## 7           6
## 8           7
## 9           1
## 10          2
```

Comment: +1. Using `as.Date(..., format...)` in the subsetting step is a bit cumbersome (if that's even what the OP had in mind), but it does have a bit more "security" than using a separate vector as I suggested in case the column order ever changes in different analyses.

Comment: Actually, looking at this some more, the second `as.Date` in your comparison is not required, right? In other words, you can change `as.Date(names(df), format = "%d.%m.%Y") > as.Date("2013-03-08")` to `as.Date(names(df), format = "%d.%m.%Y") > "2013-03-08"` and things will still work as expected. (I think.)

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are right. `df[, as.Date(names(df), format='%d.%m.%Y') > '2013-03-08', drop=FALSE]` works too